# Is it safe to send Paypal transaction ID to buyer via email?

Tags: email, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm creating an e-commerce shop using Paypal Express Checkout payment. Inside IPN callback, after [required checks](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) I send a confirmation email to buyer. Inside this e-mail I would like to include Paypal transaction ID, to let user easily communicate with vendor about order, if necessary.

Is it safe to send Paypal transaction ID to buyer via email?

Comment: I don't see why not, but it may not be any use. The buyer may have a different transaction ID. You may as well just send your own txn id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the payer will get a paypal email with the transaction id anyways.